# What is happening in the following code of a trie

Tags: c++, algorithm, trie

I was going over this [example](http://cperea.com/programming/implementation-of-a-trie-in-c/) of a Trie and I am having difficulty understanding the following code

```
void Trie::addWord(string word)
{
    Node * currentNode = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
    {
        char currentChar = tolower(word.at(i));
        int index = currentChar - 'a';
        assert(index >= 0);     // Makes sure the character is between a-z
        if (currentNode->children[index] != NULL)
        {
            // check if the current node has the current character as one of its decendants
            currentNode = currentNode->children[index];
        }
        else
        {
            // the current node doesn't have the current character as one of its decendants
            Node * newNode = new Node(currentChar);
            currentNode->children[index] = newNode;
            currentNode = newNode;
        }
        if (i == word.size() - 1)
        {
            // the last character of the word has been reached
            currentNode->end = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why is `a` being subtracted here

```
 int index = currentChar - 'a';
```

Comment: It should be `assert(index >= 0 && index < 26)` to make sure it's between `a-z` because `{` and `}` would also yield `>= 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the line `int index = currentChar - 'a';` The `currentChar` (what ever it is) will be subtracted by 'a' character which has the `ASCII` value 97. 
In this case you have two conditions:

1. First If `currentChar` is between a-z, the result of `index` will always be `>= 0`.
2. Otherwise `currentChar` is not between a-z because `index` will be negative number, currentChar can't be between `A-Z` because of the `tolower()` function.

You can refeare to this [link](http://www.newebgroup.com/academy/tables/ascii.htm) to know more about `ASCII` values

Also you need to update the condition `assert(index >= 0 && index < 26)` because { ,} ,| and ~  will make index >=0

Answer (score 1):

It will give you the letter position in alphabeta consider `a` as the position `0`. Here `a` is converted to its ASCII code and it is subsctracted from the `a-z` letter became more easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

What people tend to forget - a character is a byte with the ascii value in it.

so 'a' is 97 in the ascii table (I think), so all is being done - is currentChar-97.

please follow the http://www.asciitable.com for the actual values.

but always remember - a char is a byte, and you can use this fact a lot!
I am using it for skipping memory addresses in pointers (for example:

```
void* a = (void*)((char*)arr+2);
```

This code will return the memory of arr+ two bytes, while ignoring the type that is being held within arr)

Please do notice - |'a'-'A'| = |'A'-'a'| , but one will be negative, while the other one will be positive

Answer (score 0):

int index = currentChar - 'a'; this is to check the character because the user can enter a character that is not between a to z.